# WPF Custom ScrollBar - Zune Style ScrollBar

Tags: wpf, scrollbar, microsoft-metro

I am trying to setup a custom ScrollBar to match the Zune metro theme.  I am porting a ScrollBar from a Silverlight theme.  The code in the link below is not working though.  Any ideas?

Sample code is posted at http://pastie.org/2337083 as I can't post more than 30,000 characters here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I have solved the issue just after posting this message.  Simply changing the line #424 in Pastie snippet from:

```
<Style x:Key="DefaultScrollBarStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
```

to the following:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ScrollBar}" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
```

After changing that the issue is now resolved and the custom ScrollBar works.

Comment: These lines of code are identical. I'm not sure this is the solution!

Comment: Sorry about that I must of copy / pasted the wrong lines into the question.  I have adjusted the second line for the fix that works.

Answer (score 1):

There's a bunch of missing brushes from the pasted example.

You can get them from:

https://nroute.svn.codeplex.com/svn/nRoute4.5_Samples/Desktop/nNetflix/nRoute.Samples.Netflix/Assets/

Just add the Brushes.xaml to the ResourceDictionary.